# Vue3 access to get/set global variable within <script setup>

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

What is the best way to access and set a global variable from within a vue3 component driven by

I currently have something like this way that is working

```
  const { proxy } = getCurrentInstance()
  async function load() {
    if (!proxy.$globalVar) {
      proxy.$globalVar = "test"
    }
    return proxy.$globalVar
  }
```

but lookign though other forum posts/documentation it appears that getCurrentInstance is not really the best way to approach this situation.

Looked into provide/inject and this also could work in terms of accessing the variable and creating a new function in the main.ts to update the value, but this feels like overkill to keep a variable that all instances of a component have accesss to. (although creating a global variable for this also feels like overkill)

historically could of used something like Vue.observable but dont believe this exists in vue3 anymore.

In principle there are a few ways to get this functionally working, but just wondering what is generally considered the "best" way to do so.

Comment: How exactly is  this global variable supposed to work? Generally it's as simple as `const someVar = ref(); const useSomeVar = () => someVar`, can be changed to provide/inject to be SSR-friendly

Comment: Idea being its ment to download a JSON from online (geojson shape file, so around 20mb) but the component that uses it is used several times, at the moment every instance re-downloads the 20mb causing a slowness to the loadtime of pages (espically if its used multiple times on a page). Thinking can try and cache the download once and access it multiple times, but whats the most elegant way to do it, and keep the code clean, could use a store or something as well, but its only ever gonna be used by this component so was wondering if there is a way to keep it within the comp.

Comment: It's global to the app, despite it's used by a single component, so it makes sense to make it global store. You can use third-party (Pinia) or your own, https://vuejs.org/guide/scaling-up/state-management.html#simple-state-management-with-reactivity-api  . The alternative is keepalive component, which wouldn't work the way you need when you need several instances

Comment: yeah thought that may be the case, no worries ill put it in a store for the information, sounds like its the best way though. Thanks